# loop over an arraylist of strings

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist

I'm writing java code to loop over an `ArrayList` of `String`s. If the length of the `String` is 4, then add in front of it a certain character.
This is the code i have written. When I do things explicitly it works, but when I write the loop it doesn't and I can't find where my mistake is.

An example is below. I want the output to be ("hello", "**", "me")

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("hello");
        list.add("me");
        //without loop: this gives me correct output
        if(list.get(0).length()==2) list.add(0, "**");
        if(list.get(1).length()==2) list.add(1, "**");
        /* when i loop i get an error,
        for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++) {
            if(list.get(i).length()==2) list.add(i, "**");
        }
        */
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size() - 1` was wrong, and adding needs to skip extra.

```
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).length() == 2) {
        list.add(i, "**");
        i++; // Do skip the item
    }
}
```

BTW: one may write:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, "hello", "me");
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot the addAll method

Answer (score -1):

You could use an enhanced for loop to loop through all of the string and have direct access instead of having to index to access them.

```
for (String s : list)
{
    /* CODE */
}
```

And instead of having to use the `get` method to access the string and it's length, you can just use the `s` variable and use `s.length()`

Comment: This will result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`. OP is changing the `ArrayList` as they iterate over it.

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> newList= new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("hello");
            list.add("me");
            for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                if(list.get(i).length()==2)
                    newList.add("**");
                else
                    newList.add(list.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println(newList);
}
```

Comment: No, Why do I need to increment i ? there is new ArrayList that adds only the value. Just try and you will see. Thanks!

Comment: OP wants to add _to the existing list_. Please demonstrate how to get the added values into the existing list.